# Need to get a text from the application using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, text

[image: Screenhot html]I need to validate a text area from the application please help me how to get the value from the application.

HTML structure mentioned in below snap. I need to validate the text should be labeled as "Completed"

[image]

Comment: Can you show the `td` tag data where 'Completed' level present. add the html of that not image

Comment: In the provided html we are not seeing anything you are talking about. please show us element in html that you are talking about with expand

Comment: I have added another screenshot.Sorry i am in cleint system cant share the html code :(.Restriction

Comment: No I am asking only screenshot where it was showing complete text we are unable to see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as mentioned below.

Xpath:

//table[@id='tblImportLoanResults']//tr[@class='tablelightrow']/td[contains(text(),'Completed')]

or

//table[@id='tblImportLoanResults']//tr[@class='tablelightrow']/td[12]

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the webelement")).getText();
if(text.equals("Completed")){
//to do something
 }
else{
//to do something
 }
```

Try it and let me know if you have any queries

Comment: Actually I am unable to get the xpath of the element.so i need to get the xpath of the element.elemnt is a string "completed" and i need to print that element..by giving the xpath of the label.

Comment: Then show us the html screenshot or code for this element then we can help you in finding xpath.

Comment: Hi Akarsh...I have added the full html screenshot in the question

Comment: See I added xpath try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate that row using text itself and then get the text using following xpath

```
//table[@id='tblImportLoanResults']//tr[@class='tablelightrow']/td[contains(text(),'Completed')]
```

Your last td contains the lable so you can use `last()` method in xpath as well

`//table[@id='tblImportLoanResults']//tr[@class='tablelightrow']/td[last()]`

Comment: Thank you ..it works.....actually I need to get the text of the row and it changes from "in progress" to "completed" so how to get the text value without using contains(text(),'Completed'....can I use //table[@id='tblImportLoanResults']//tr[@class='tablelightrow']/td[@class='displaylabel']/[12]

Comment: @bitan, yes you can. also the completed text present under your last td so you can use `last()` function as well in xpath  `//table[@id='tblImportLoanResults']//tr[@class='tablelightrow']/td[last()]`